# WARNING vsh: [bus.cc(638)] Bus::SendWithReplyAndBlock took 30029ms to process

Tags: terminal

I run Linux Debian/Ubuntu on my Chromebook. Sometimes when I have VS Code open and when I try to open the terminal, I get this error:

```
WARNING vsh: [bus.cc(638)] Bus::SendWithReplyAndBlock took 30029ms to process message: type=method_call, path=/org/chromium/VmCicerone, interface=org.chromium.VmCicerone, member=LaunchVshd
ERROR vsh: [object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.chromium.VmCicerone.LaunchVshd: object_path= /org/chromium/VmCicerone: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
ERROR vsh: [vsh.cc(137)] Failed to send dbus message to cicerone service
```

Can anyone help me get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turns out that it was just lag.**

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you determined that this was the reason for the problem?

Comment: I had multiple programs open. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356204/terminal-shell-doesnt-work is related. The error message came when I try to load the terminal shell. In that other question, I found out a simple update resolved the problem. Everything worked out after that.